# C# apply app.config transformation not working from parent level to child

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, console-application

I am trying to apply a transformation to child elements in my service app.config.
I have several services and I need to replace only one attribute.

**Sample service entry**

```
<configuration>
     <cronService>
            <cronSettings>
                <services>
                    <service name="Name1" assembly="xxx.yyy.Applications.dll" interval="300" wakeUpTime="" onErrorEmail="developmentteam@zzz.com" continueAfterError="true" notifyEmailOnError="true" runOnStart="true" enable="true" />
    <service name="Name2" assembly="xxx.lll.Applications.dll" interval="300" wakeUpTime="" onErrorEmail="developmentteam@zzz.com" continueAfterError="true" notifyEmailOnError="true" runOnStart="true" enable="true" />
                </services>
            </cronSettings>
        </cronService>
</configuration>
```

In the transform file, I tried to apply xdt:Transform at the parent level and expecting the child to get changed

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <cronService>
        <cronSettings emailSender="{AppTierCloudService}@zzz.com" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" >
        <services xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" >
            <service onErrorEmail="developmentteam@www.com, abb@www.com"/>
        </services>
        </cronSettings>
    </cronService>
</configuration>
```

referred this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx.

But the transformation is not happening. Any help?

Comment: it is I have updated

Comment: What happens if you run your example XML through https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/? It works for me so please explain what it does and what you need it to do.

Comment: Transform is not happening. Basically, I am trying to change onErrorEmail attribute value from "developmentteam@zzz.com" to "developmentteam@www.com, abb@www.com".
Anyway thanks for that site which is saving lot of my time.

Comment: adding xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" in the child works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"` in the child works.

```xml
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <cronService>
        <cronSettings emailSender="{AppTierCloudService}@zzz.com" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes">
            <services>
                <service onErrorEmail="developmentteam@www.com, abb@www.com" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" />
            </services>
        </cronSettings>
    </cronService>
</configuration>
```

After transformation the XML looks like this:

```xml
<configuration>
    <cronService>
        <cronSettings emailSender="{AppTierCloudService}@zzz.com">
            <services>
                <service name="Name1" assembly="xxx.yyy.Applications.dll" interval="300" wakeUpTime="" onErrorEmail="developmentteam@www.com, abb@www.com" continueAfterError="true" notifyEmailOnError="true" runOnStart="true" enable="true" />
                <service name="Name2" assembly="xxx.lll.Applications.dll" interval="300" wakeUpTime="" onErrorEmail="developmentteam@www.com, abb@www.com" continueAfterError="true" notifyEmailOnError="true" runOnStart="true" enable="true" />
            </services>
        </cronSettings>
    </cronService>
</configuration>
```

Special thanks to @Kirk Larkin  for showing this instant transform checker tool:  https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com.